# Magento manufacture contacts

Tags: magento

Maybe somebody know, how add via Magento backend contacts (like phone,fax,email etc) for manufacturer? Will be glad to any decision.
Magento extensions also accepted )

tnx

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question per se. It may or may not be a better fit for http://magento.stackexchange.com/. See their faq and help pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this extension you can add contact details http://www.fmeaddons.com/magento/shop-by-manufacturer-brands-extension.html